# XAML globalization using resources in combobox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, localization, winrt-xaml

I am [globalizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx) my WinRT app and I can't use language resources in my comboboxs. I can use it in my TextBlocks using **Text** property but not using **x:string**. What am I doing wrong?

```
TextBlock x:Uid="Priority" Text="Default"></TextBlock>
<ComboBox>
     <x:String x:Uid="Color">Default1</x:String>
     <x:String x:Uid="Color.Text">Default2</x:String>
</ComboBox>
```

**EDIT**

Why can't I populate ComboBox elements with resource strings in XAML code? I know that I can add TextBlock elements inside ComboBox to use dictionaries or, as I am doing now, load them through code but this is not the response to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know when you use  in xaml that is a compile time constant which will not be able to change at runtime and bind to a resource. That is why you probably see Default1 or Default2 as items in your combobox.

I was able to find a solution to your problem.

The idea is that in the combobox you should use ComboBoxItem and set the x:Uid to the value of the resource. But in the resource file, the actual name should be Name.Content, because ComboBoxItem has a ContentPresenter in it as default and not a TextBlock.

So this is the code that worked for me:
In the resource file I have:

```
Combo.Content        ComboBox1
```

And in the Xaml I used:

```
<ComboBox>
   <ComboBoxItem x:Uid="Combo" />
</ComboBox>
```

This will populate the ComboBox with an item "ComboBox1" (from the resource file).

I have not tested this to see if it works with resource files for different languages, but I see no reason why it should not work.

Comment: +1 Yes, I tried and it works. Why didn't I remember to try ComboBoxItem? -.- Probably this will be the answer and I will give you the bounty. However there are 5 days left and I will wait to see if another solution using **<x:String>** shows up. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect (but haven't found specific statement in documentation), that the entries in resource.resw would need to be (dependency?) properties of the objects for the automatic resource binding to work.  Strings don't have such properties; `Default1` isn't a value for `String.Content`, for example.

Path of least resistance would be using TextBlock for you ComboBox elements. Alternatively, you could load the resource in code and assign it to the string that way.

Comment: I thought of filling my ComboBox elements through code but it is weird that I cannot use string resources in XAML without adding more elements with Text property

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything preventing you from using a binding for the ComboBox's ItemsSource? That way you could use a custom object that contains the information you need, as well as a `DisplayName` property, which can then get the correct resource string from the .resx file.

If that's not an option at all, I'm not sure right now what the solution would be to do the whole thing entirely in XAML.

Comment: No, I can easily bind data read from resources to ItemsSource. However I have this habit of making my code the shorter possible and do the whole thing entirely in XAML seems the right way but my researches didn't show me why I can't do it.